# react native app not showing console logs in the Terminal window of vscode

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code, logging, console, native

there appears also nothing in the other tabs "output" or "debug console"[image]

I tried to look in the terminal, theoOutput and the debug console window

blablablablablablablablablablablblablablablablablablablablablablalblalblab

Answer (score 0):

As I see you didn't run the app, you must use Emulator or Scan QR Code with your own phone.

Link for documentation expo emulator : https://docs.expo.dev/workflow/android-studio-emulator/